# TortoiseSVN command keeps open processes

Tags: batch-file, svn, cmd, tortoisesvn

I am using a scheduled task to run a .bat script which updates my SVN repositories.


The scheduled task runs every hour. It still creating a new process of "TortoiseProc.exe", every time I run the script, until the are a lot of open processes and the CPU is at 99%. The script is running fine, but **unfortunately the processes won't be closed automatically.**

This is how my .bat looks like:

```
CD C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\
START /wait TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"D:\somePath" /closeonend:1
START /wait TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"D:\somePath" /closeonend:1
```

As you can see I added `/closeonend:1` which means the dialog should be closed if no error occurs.


When I run the .bat script manually, no process is created.

Does someone has a suggestion, what to do? I really would appreciate it!

Comment: `START "" /wait TortoiseProc.exe …` [Always include a `TITLE` this can be a simple string like `"My Script"` or just a pair of empty quotes `""`](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html). According to the Microsoft documentation, the _title_ is optional, but depending on the other options chosen you can have problems if it is omitted.

Comment: @JosefZ I tried it but unfortunately it didn't work. But thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: You should not use TortoiseProc to automate such operations. Use `svn.exe`. Generally speaking, TortoiseProc should be used for GUI automation only. The very first important 'Warning' from the documentation tells: **If you want to write a script which requires no input, you should use the official Subversion command line client instead.** https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html#tsvn-automation

Comment: You're right. I will try that out. Thanks for the information :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `tortoiseproc` for unattended/non-interactive scripting (automation) - use `svn.exe` instead, which is shipped with TortoiseSVN.

```
CD C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\
svn update "D:\somePath"
svn update "D:\somePath"
```