# Tortoise SVN command line update with username and password

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn, command-line-interface

I'm using following command to automate svn update using TortoiseSVN

```
C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe /command:log /path:"c:\MyRepo\"
```

But I don't want to save svn login on the GUI. So how can i feed the login on this command?

Comment: From [the manual](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html): _"Remember that TortoiseSVN is a GUI client, and this automation guide shows you how to make the TortoiseSVN dialogs appear to collect user input. If you want to write a script which requires no input, you should use the official Subversion command line client instead."_

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TortoiseSVN command keeps open processes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039658/tortoisesvn-command-keeps-open-processes)

Comment: Take the answer at the linked (duplicate) question and add `--username` and `--password` on the command line for `svn.exe`