# Windows Batch Script: Writing to log file causes "used by another process"

Tags: batch-file, svn, tortoisesvn

I need to update multiple SVN working copies. I want to write this to a log file, but it isn't possible, because one SVN update takes only a few seconds and a different one maybe up to minutes.

Due of that, I'm always getting the following message:

```
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

I'm using this code:

```
@echo off
echo.

:: Setting Variables
set SVN_BIN=C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe
set LOG_FILE=D:\BatchScripts\logs\svn-update.log
set CMD_TITLE="SVNUpdate"
set SOURCE1=D:\www\upload.example.com\
set SOURCE2=D:\www\download.example.com\
set SOURCE3=D:\www\client.example.com\
::
::
echo. %DATE% %TIME% Updating %SOURCE1% using SVN... >> "%LOG_FILE%"
START "%CMD_TITLE%" "%SVN_BIN%" /command:update /path:"%SOURCE1%" /closeonend:1 >> "%LOG_FILE%"
::
echo. %DATE% %TIME% Updating %SOURCE2% using SVN... >> "%LOG_FILE%"
START "%CMD_TITLE%" "%SVN_BIN%" /command:update /path:"%SOURCE2%" /closeonend:1 >> "%LOG_FILE%"
::
echo. %DATE% %TIME% Updating %SOURCE3% using SVN... >> "%LOG_FILE%"
START "%CMD_TITLE%" "%SVN_BIN%" /command:update /path:"%SOURCE3%" /closeonend:1 >> "%LOG_FILE%"
::
echo. %DATE% %TIME% Operation complete. >> "%LOG_FILE%"
```

How can I archive to write a log file? The script will be executed every 5 minutes using Windows task scheduler.

The `START` parameter `/wait` does not help or fix the problem, but it does slow down the update process a lot, because it always waits for the current SVN update to finish and then, it will start the next update. That's not, what I want.

Comment: Use a different log for every source?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TortoiseSVN command keeps open processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039658/tortoisesvn-command-keeps-open-processes)

Comment: @Compo No, that's a different problem. I'm talking about redirecting something to a log file. This post is talking about non-closing TortoiseSVN processes.

Comment: @LotPings That also doesn't help. I've already tried to only log the `echo`, but this has also already the problem.

Comment: @Sebbo, you are trying to run several non interactive commands using an interactive command process. The advice in the post I linked was clear, **If you want to write a script which requires no input, you should use the official Subversion command line client instead**. My suggestion therefore is that you try doing just that and feed back the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TortoiseProc.exe is not the tool for this task. You should use `svn.exe` for this kind of automation. Read the [documentation](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html):

> Remember that TortoiseSVN is a GUI client, and this automation guide
>   shows you how to make the TortoiseSVN dialogs appear to collect user
>   input. If you want to write a script which requires no input, you
>   should use the official Subversion command line client instead.

Comment: Great - thanks for the information! How-to get `svn.exe`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967176/where-is-svn-exe-in-my-machine